# Registering click event and animations in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

When I click on an element of the accordion list, all elements expand. I want to open just the card whose header has been clicked.

**[plnkr link here](https://embed.plnkr.co/8OfFxSzwOOLfGFnrp6Ts/)**

**app.component.html**

```
        <div id="accordion" *ngIf="res">
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let r of res;let i=index">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" 
                        (click)="toggleShowDiv(i)">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="a{{i}}" [@slideInOut]="animationState">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                               dnf ksdfkg skdfgk sd mkdfdm
                               d kmfsd mdksm dk mdf
                               d kdm kd kdsmfk sd
                                sdfsdkg sdkm gdkg dk
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SlideInOutAnimation } from './animation';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
animations: [SlideInOutAnimation]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
res = [1, 2, 3, 4];
animationState = 'out';
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
ngOnInit() {

}
toggleShowDiv(id) {
    this.animationState = this.animationState === 'out' ? 'in' : 
 'out';
  }
}
```

How can I animate the card body to expand when it has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are generating all four elements of list using `*ngFor` loop and applying *one* click action on *all* of them. You have to correctly fetch the `id` of the collapsible element and apply the animation *only on that element*.

Here is a solution.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SlideInOutAnimation } from './animation';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    animations: [SlideInOutAnimation]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    modelsList: { id: number, header: string, text: string, animationState: string }[] = [
        { "id": 0, "header": "Some header", "text": "Some text", "animationState": "out" },
        { "id": 1, "header": "Some header", "text": "Some text", "animationState": "out" },
        { "id": 2, "header": "Some header", "text": "Some text", "animationState": "out" },
        { "id": 3, "header": "Some header", "text": "Some text", "animationState": "out" }
    ]; 

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    ngOnInit() {

    }
    toggleShowDiv(id) {
        this.modelsList[id].animationState = this.modelsList[id].animationState === "out" ? 'in' : "out";
      }
      objectKeys(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj);
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div id="accordion" *ngIf="modelsList">
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(modelsList); let i=index" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="toggleShowDiv(i)">
                                {{modelsList[i].header}}
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="a{{i}}" [@slideInOut]="modelsList[i].animationState">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                   {{modelsList[i].text}}
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The text and headers of your accordion list has been moved to `TS` code, which makes it easier to apply element-wise operations. There might be a way to do this from `HTML` as well but I haven't looked into that.